# Android external allocation too large, but why?

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I have a large image 1.28 MB (1,343,488 bytes) that I use in my app, however I wanted to change a few things and created a new image that was instead only 292 KB (299,008 bytes) in size.  I created both images in Photoshop 7.0, saved them both as .png and both as interlaced.  I have been creating this app around the larger image, and as soon as I switch to the smaller image, I get an OutOfMemory error with my bitmap saying

`12108912-byte external allocation too large for this process`

why does it think my new image is 11.5 MB?  if i switch images back to the larger one, it compiles correctly.

```
private Bitmap loadMapBitmap() {
    Log.d("InteractiveMap", "loadBitmap");
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {   
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.map);
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadMapBitmap - " + e.toString());
        finish();
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        Log.d("InteractiveMap", "too big " + e.getMessage());
        finish();
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

I dont get why the much smaller image doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

It's the image resolution. The file size is not relevant. When you load a bitmap into memory, each pixel takes 4 bytes when using the `ARGB8888` format
(which is the [default one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPreferredConfig) for `BitmapFactory.decode..()`).

Example: A 640x480 pixel sized image takes `640*480*4` bytes, which is 1200kB in memory.
This is completely independend from the file-format used to compress this image (PNG, JPEG, ..) and filesize.

In extreme cases these sizes differ a lot. E.g. you create a huge image which consists of one color. That's pretty great when it comes to file compression. But in memory it will take a lot of space.

Comment: oh, I should have mentioned, its a smaller image in dimensions too.  its 2365x1784 for the larger image, and 2082x1454 :/

Comment: That smaller one is still 11.54 MB in memory, which is exactly your allocation. Most likely your app has other resources opened in memory. Depending on the device, the limit of memory that you can allocate might be as low as 16MB total. I can't tell you much without seeing your whole app code. I'd recommend to inspect your memory allocation and see what you can optimize. See [this session](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/memory-management-for-android-apps.html) from the Google I/O for a nice introduction to memory analysis.

Comment: thanks for the help, I copy and pasted my photoshop image to MS paint and that seemed to work, so I dont know if there was some mysterious option I have set, but the png from photoshop wont load, but the one from paint does, so I guess I got some more to learn, thanks alex :)

Comment: Ok, I don't understand why this works, but glad I could help. ;)

Comment: I think because I was using photoshop, it was saving my .png with transparency, even though I had no transparency, so saving in MS paint removed the transparency that was saved in the .png file.  That's how I reasoned it.